# There is a way to know when the user copy a photo to camera roll album by usb connection?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to get an event when a file is added on the "camera roll" album by a usb connection.
I thought in create a task to verify if the "camera roll" album is increasing or decreasing their size. But this will be very cost in the performance. So i am trying to find an event that tells me when the system file be altered.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WinRT** provides files and folders monitoring based on queries, which is an alternative to the *.net* `FileSystemWatcher` class, your app also needs to be subscribed on the query's `ContentsChanged` event to get notified

```
 private void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var query = KnownFolders.CameraRoll.CreateFileQuery();
        query.ContentsChanged += QueryContentsChanged; 
        await query.GetFilesAsync();
    }
    void QueryContentsChanged(Windows.Storage.Search.IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
    {
        // your handler code
    }
```

**Update**

the `GetFilesAsync` is necessary to trigger the `ContentsChanged` event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is exactly what i want. But this event will be implemented only in windows 10 sdk right? There is something related in windows phone 8.1?

Comment: Are you sure? I made a POC with the code that you passed. And when i ran an exception was fired on line "var query = KnownFolders.CameraRoll.CreateFileQuery();". Follows the exception stacktrace

{System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.CreateFileQuery()
   at GeneralPOC.MainPage.MainPage_OnLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)}

Comment: Well, i have an issue running windows phone apps on my PC, the event is fired as expected in a Winrt Project (Store app), I've tried it with the LocalFolder, and nothing on the msdn docs says that it ain't supported on WP or something  !!
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.storagefolderqueryresult.contentschanged

Comment: You can tell me how you testing your code? Now i running my POC on a device with windows 10 mobile insider preview. And the exception is not fired anymore. But while my POC is running i connect the device and start delete some photos on camera roll but the breakpoint inside the method subscribed on event ContentsChanged is not reached.

Comment: I used CreateFileAsync and DeleteAsync and set a break point on the ContentsChanged  event hander , and the event was fired as expected, ... and as i told you i tried it on the LocalFolder (since CameraRoll is a Windows Phone thing) in a store app

Comment: I try use CreateFileAsync and DeleteAsync in LocalFolder but the event is not fired too...
Are you testing on a real device or in the emulator?

Comment: I see this on documentation page of the event ContentsChanged:
"Fires when a file is added to, deleted from, or modified in the folder being queried. This event only fires after GetFilesAsync has been called at least once."
So i have call the GetFilesAsync before manipulate the folder right?

Comment: No, not necessarily, here the sample project that i am running https://github.com/SamTheDev/WinRtSample/blob/master/App9/MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: My project was equal to yours. The only difference is on this line: "var files = await query.GetFilesAsync ();". Without this line, the event is not triggered. So from what I understand the GetFilesAsync () is actually necessary, right?

Comment: Yes mate, apparently i missed that, thanx for keep digging, i will update the answer